# Djnago superuser is not created properly?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

## Super user is creating when i removed one of the seeting AUTH_USER_MODEL & in models AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin  and added (models.Model) otherwise it is not creating the superuser..

```
 models.py 
 =============
 import django
 from django.db import models

 import django.utils.timezone
 from django.conf import settings
 from django.db.models.signals import post_save
 from django.dispatch import receiver
 from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
 from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
 from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
 from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

 from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
 from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
 import datetime,calendar
 import uuid
 class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
      use_in_migrations = True

     def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
         """
          Creates and saves a User with the given mobile and password.
          """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
            # email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

     def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
         extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
         return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

     def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
         extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
         extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

         if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
             raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

         return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
      username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
      fullname = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
      email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True, null=True)
      is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=True,)
      is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
      is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('is_superuser'))
      objects =  UserManager()
```

some fields are shownig errors plese check in attached picture
[reemaing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVeOL.jpg)

## model.py

[this is my UserProfile code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SpD3.jpg)

Comment: Please add your custom user model to the question and the error that appears when creating a `superuser`.

Comment: please check once